# Flexbox equal-height elements, with dynamic height, without specifying a height or ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm not sure Flexbox can do this, but it seems to be getting close:
http://codepen.io/timkelty/pen/XbKzaQ

```
.Nav {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 700px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.Nav-column {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Nav-hdg {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.Nav-content {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to have the `.Nav-hdg` elements be the same height, and vertically centered across the columns. I don't want to specify a height, however, I want the height to be the height of the tallest `.Nav-hdg`.

Anyone know how to tackle this, or if flexbox can do this?

Here's a rough mockup of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: Its a bit hard to describe, I know. I attached an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Flexbox isn't going to help here I would suggest, The columns are not related to one another in that way to be affected by the flex properties. I.E. One heading is not related to another heading in a different column.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's what I figured. Bummer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define different flex box for headings and a different one for the content. This way you can specify `justify-content: space-around;` for the headings and `justify-content: flex-start;` for the content.

See this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLjrRP

Comment: Thanks. Not ideal from a markup standpoint, but I think this is the only way to pull this off.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see would be to semantically separate headings, and to switch from `flex-flow: column` to `flex-flow: row`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

header, article {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;
}

header {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>A flex child</h1>
  </header>
  <header>
    <h1>A flex child with wrapping text, and therefore taller</h1>
  </header>
  <header>
    <h1>Another flex child</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
    </ul>
  </article>
</main>
```